# Django,HTML , connecting template to js,css

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django project that contains a landing page.

I worked on it outside the project and the HTML page was able to route to the js and CSS files and it worked great.

Once I copied the folder into the project's templates folder (as shown in the structure below),
And added routes and views in the project as required The server ran okay and open the page,
But it's showing only the HTML and cannot refer to raises errors when trying to refer to the js scripts.

for example:

Not Found: /templates/js/main.js
[19/Mar/2020 08:22:12] "GET /templates/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2490

```
# home.hmtl

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="yovelcohen" content="Sumon Rahman"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Triangulation Calculator</title>
    <!-- Plugin-CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/owl.carousel.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/linearicons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/magnific-popup.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/animate.css"/>
    <!-- Main-Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/responsive.css"/>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- MainMenu-Area-End -->
<!-- Home-Area -->
<header class="home-area overlay" id="home_page">

</header>
<!-- Home-Area-End -->
<!-- About-Area -->
  # some HTML stuff ...

    <!-- Footer-Area-End -->
    <!--Vendor-JS-->
    <script src="templates/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/js/vendor/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--Plugin-JS-->
    <script src="templates/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/js/contact-form.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/js/ajaxchimp.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/js/scrollUp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/js/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <!--Main-active-JS-->
    <script src="templates/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My templates folder:

```
.
├── css
│   ├── animate.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── linearicons.css
│   ├── magnific-popup.css
│   ├── normalize.css
│   ├── owl.carousel.min.css
│   └── responsive.css
├── fonts
│   ├── Linearicons-Free.eot
│   ├── Linearicons-Free.svg
│   ├── Linearicons-Free.ttf
│   ├── Linearicons-Free.woff
│   └── Linearicons-Free.woff2
├── home.html
├── images
│   ├── # Some images..
├── js
│   ├── ajaxchimp.js
│   ├── contact-form.js
│   ├── magnific-popup.min.js
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── owl.carousel.min.js
│   ├── scrollUp.min.js
│   ├── vendor
│   └── wow.min.js
└── style.css
```

How the webpage is seen:

[image]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 2):

you need to manage static files. Refer this : [doc_link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)
Also, you should not put static files like CSS, js into templates folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at static files as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60753800/12940362), you need to create a separate folder for css and js files and set it as a static file, or add a folder to the add folder

for example, in my site, it is like this:

```
|   admin.py
|   apps.py
|   models.py
|   tests.py
|   urls.py
|   views.py
|   
+---static
|   \---finance
|       +---css
|       |       main.css
|       |       
|       \---js
|               main.js
|               
\---templates
    \---finance
            about.html
            base.html
            home.html
```

then at the top of your file use `{% load static %}` and use `{% static "app-name/foo.txt" %}`
For more information look at [Django's how-to guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) on static files

Answer (score 0):

In Django only(normally) html files are in the template folder.

1. Move your .js and .css files to "project/app_name/static" folder.
   This "static" folder normally doesn't create on app creation.
   You have to create this folder manually.
2. put static settings in settings.py in the project folder.
3. use Django urls as below

```
{# in your page head/before any js,css file #}
{% load static %}


{# for any css,js file > load urls as below #}

<script src="{% static 'dist/myn.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app.css' %}"/>
```

4. in debug=true
   add below code at end of in project urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- add below Django command to use bootstrap3 in web page.  -->
    {% load bootstrap3 %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript %}
    <!-- first load django static tag. -->
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <!-- use django static tag ton load js file and css file. -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”{% static 'css/dept_emp_style.css' %}”>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- include web page navigation bar page -->
            {% include "./base_menu_bar.html" %}
            {% block page_content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```